# Spring data with Elasticsearch 6.4.2 is not working for Java hashmap properties

Tags: java, elasticsearch, mapping

## Mapping java Object to elasticSearch document using @Document

@Document(createIndex = true, indexName = "djacency", type = "djacency")
    public class djacencyDoc {

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Object)
    private Agent agent1 = null;
}
```

### Class values set before save:

class Agent {
            prop6: 480
            prop7: class FAttributes7{
                attr1Name : [class FAttributes {
                    dscp: 12
                    txInterval: 100
                    padding: 425
                }, class FAttributes {
                    dscp: 14
                    txInterval: 100
                    padding: 425
                }]
            }
            listIps: class RProperties {
                attProperties: {PRASANTA3=class AttProperty {
                    Ip: 192.168.57.39
                    Agent: PRASANTA1
                    dstId: PRASANTA2
                }}
            }
            iIp: 192.168.57.53
            ip1: 255.255.255.78
            ip4: 192.168.57.187
            testId: null
            klan: 0
            Priority: 0
            Id: p1
        }
        ntinuity: null
        voip: null
        netqr: null
    }

```
 Here "listIps" value is "RProperties" which is a Java Hashmap ,Before save it has some value but While saving into elasticsearch RProperties value is saved as null.
```

### Class values get after save:

```
Agent: class Agent2 {
        prop1: true
        prop2: 50000
        prop3: 50000
        prop4: 300
        prop5: null
        prop6: 480
        prop7: class Agent3 {
            attr1Name : [class FAttributes {
                dscp: 12
                txInterval: 100
                padding: 425
            }, class FAttributes {
                dscp: 14
                txInterval: 100
                padding: 425
            }]
        }
        listIps: class RProperties {
            RProperties: null
        }
        iIp: 192.168.57.53
        sunet: 255.255.255.78
        gway: 192.168.57.187
        testId: null
        van: 0
        vriority: 0
        phyId: p1
    }
    sContinuity: null
    ip: null
    nQuality: null
}

Why for hashmap properties  "RProperties" elasticseach saves null ? The above document is saving correctly when i am using postman or curl, But from my SpringBoot Application using Spring DATA it is not working .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
listIps:class RProperties{  
   attProperties:{  
      PRASANTA3=class AttProperty{  
         Ip:192.168.57.39;
         Agent:PRASANTA1 ;
         dstId:PRASANTA2
      }
   }
}

The above code should be like below format,

listIps:class RProperties extends HashMap<String,AttProperty>{       
      "PRASANTA3"=class AttProperty{  
         Ip:192.168.57.39;
         Agent:PRASANTA1 ;
         dstId:PRASANTA2
      }
}


Here RProperties class should extends from Hashmap , instead of RProperties contains one more class (AttProperties) which again contains the hashmap properties.

Here RProperties is a HashMap which contains key("PRASANTA3"),value(AttProperty class values) .
```